# Custom UIPickerView to have unselectable first row

Tags: iphone

I'd like to create a custom `UIPickerView` in iOS that will present the elements of the picker to the user, but have a "blank" selection at the top.  If the user doesn't select anything then the result from the `UIPickerView` is `nil`.  If the user scrolls down to select something, then it just returns to proper index in the list.

The problem with the `UIPickerView` is that when you come into it, it looks like the user has at least selected the first element.

I would like to "force" the user to pick something.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

can't you just make the first item in the datasource a @""?

Comment: No, because then the "" in the list is index 0.  I want the first element to be the first real element in the list.